# Does -istisch, -ismisch translate to -istic, -ismic?

Tags: translation, adjective, german-to-english, suffix

I intend to translate the German term *perspektivismische Kritik.* It is intended to mean criticism from people with an attitude characterised by its emphasis on perspective.

[Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_griechischer_Suffixe) tells me that in German, to designate the attitude of a group, you use the Greek suffix *-ismus* (e.g. *Funktion → Funktionalismus, Pluralität → Pluralismus).*

By making an adjective from the noun, *Perspektivismus* becomes *perspektivismisch.* This means something different than *perspektivistisch* or even *perspektivisch. Perspektivisch* is **from** a perspective. With *perspektivistisch* I am not sure, either it is **with regard** for a perspective or it is just plain wrong.

Now my question is: Do these derivatives translate one-to-one into English, i.e.:

> perspektivismisch → perspectivismic
>   perspektivistisch → perspectivistic
>   perspektivisch → ?

Comment: Sounds more like it should be posted in english.sx.

Comment: Perspektivisch?

Comment: I figured the intersection of English _and_ German speakers is greater here. @Toscho: Why do you think so? At first sight it seems like both platforms are equally relevant...

Comment: @Robert: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @wehnsdaefflae: Dass sowohl "perspektivismisch" als auch "perspektivistisch" falsch klingen.

Comment: @Robert: Komisch klingen so Wortungetüme in der Philosophie leider meistens. Geben tut sie's aber leider trotzdem. Zumindest im Fall des Perspektivismus, zu "perspektivistisch" hab ich ja geschrieben, dass ich mir nicht sicher bin.

Comment: @wehnsdaefflae You are asking for english words. By the other comments, you can see that we prefer talking about the meaning in German, but not how to translate this into English.

Comment: `perspektivisch` bedeutet „aus einer besonderen Perspektive heraus“. `perspektivistisch` bedeutet „unter Berücksichtigung der oder mit besonderem Augenmerk auf der Tatsache, dass mehrere Perspektiven existieren.“. `perspektivismisch` bedeutet „Perspektiven oder perspektivistische Betrachtungen toll finden“;;; Zum Vergleich dazu `relativ`, `relativistisch` und `Relativismus`.

Comment: @Toscho: I see... thanks for your advice! I could rephrase the question something like this: Does the German "perspektivismisch" mean the same like the English "perspectivismic"?

Comment: @wehnsdaefflae That question would be better, but it's still difficult, for at least me, I don't know exactly, what `perspectivismic` means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, these suffixes cannot always be translated 1:1 between German and English.

The English translation of "perspektivismisch" ought to be "perspectivic", according to Merriam-Webster "of, relating to, or concerned with perspectivism". The English translation of "perspektivisch" is "perspectively" ("of, relating to, employing, or seen in perspective").

Answer (score 2):

This is a question of word formation, of which natural language processing using programming could prove useful. You could cross-reference all words with the desired suffixes and get useful statistics on the number of matches. You would have to look at the semantics in each case to determine the number of times that the meaning overlaps (time-consuming process that would be difficult to program). Even if there were a one-to-one relationship between affixes, it would most likely have a margin of error.

One such language to program this would be Python using the [Natural Language Took Kit (NLTK)](http://www.nltk.org).

Note that a similar procedure is used to determine which words should be included in a printed dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no 1-1 correspondence.

Counterexamples for the ending *-istisch*:

- *antimonopolistisch* → it can also be translated as *anti-monopoly*
- *biologistisch* → it is also an adverb, so it can be translated  as *biologistically*.
- *deistisch* → same case, it might be *deistic* but it's an adverb as well (deistically), whence there's no 1:1 translation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think though that _seismisch_ may not be a good counterexample as it derives from _Seismik_. Therefore the suffix _-ismisch_ is not motivated by semantics but rather an artefact from the original word stem.

Comment: @wehnsdaefflae I erased that. But, unfortunately, I couldn't find any `*-ismisch` ending.